# Lens not attached message on nikon d5000 with nikon 24-70mm

Tags: lens, nikon, cleaning, lens-mount, nikon-d5000

I recently bought a Nikon 24-70mm for my D5000, but I soon had the "lens not attached" message on my screen. The message disappears when I slightly rotate the lens a bit more.

I've searched online and found the advice to clean the connectors on the lens, but I already had these connection problems on the first day that I got it. I first thought that it was because of the cold that day, (max -5°) but now when the days are warmer, I still have this problem. Every time I rotate my lens to zoom, the lens loses the connection with the body.

Is it possible something is broken on my body or lens or should I try to clean the elements myself? I'm not experienced with cleaning my gear, is there a step by step tutorial available for this?

Answer (score 2):

I would try another lens to rule out a fault with the body or try a different body if possible?

You could walk into a cam shop and ask to try a lens out maybe?

I would imagine the lens and cam are still under warranty click [here](http://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/service_support/Support_Repair_Home.page?lid=3&lidsub1=0&lidsub2=0&lidsub3=0&lidsub4=0&sParamValueLbl=&sParamValue=&dcr=) for the UK repair centre - Belgium one is [here](http://www.nikon.be/fr_BE/service_support/support_centredereparations.page?lang=)

I would also advise against cleaning anything you are not sure about - you could invalidate your warranty if something went wrong.

Comment: I think Thomas is Belgian, judging by his website address...

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i tried already with other lenses. No problem with that. I'll try a different body, but not sure when i'll have the opportunity. I'll check the repair center and call the shop where i bought the lens. It was in rotterdam. Thanks for your help.